# Button background color is not set in wpf application when a conditional property is set via code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have got a button in one of my usercontrols whose background needs to be changed based on a property set. no matter what the value of Property is set (true or false), background color is never changed. I even noticed during debugging that value of property is set to true but the trigger is not fired to set the background color.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WpfApplication1.SubToolbar"
x:Name="SubToolBar" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                    <Grid Margin="8">
                        <Ellipse  Name="r1" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="2 2" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <Border Name="border"  Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CircleButton" TargetType="Button">

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ Binding Path= Background12,   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=OneWay}"/>


        <Style.Triggers>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RiskHighLowMedium }"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ Binding Path= Background12,   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>


 <Border Background="#FFD4BFAE" CornerRadius="5" >
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox  Grid.Column="0"  Padding="5" Text="{Binding  Path=ID}"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0,0,0" Padding="5" Text="{Binding  Path=Name}"/>

        <Button Name="highLowRisk" Padding="5" Grid.Column="2" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{StaticResource CircleButton}" Margin="5,5,5,5" />







    </Grid>
 </Border>
```

I am setting the style template like this in the xaml file.

but nothing seems to change the background color.

the code below is

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for SubToolbar.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class SubToolbar : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// default ctor
    /// </summary>
    public SubToolbar()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// setting whethere 
    /// risk is high or low
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_riskhighLow"></param>
    public void SetRiskHighLow(bool _riskhighLow)
    {
        _riskHighLowMedium = _riskhighLow;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("RiskHighLowMedium");
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Background12");

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// RiskHighLowMedium
    /// </summary>

    private bool _riskHighLowMedium;

    /// <summary>
    /// property to set risk high
    /// low and medium
    /// </summary>
    public bool RiskHighLowMedium
    {
        get { return _riskHighLowMedium; }
        set
        {
                _riskHighLowMedium = value;

                this.OnPropertyChanged("RiskHighLowMedium");
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Background12");

        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// background property
    /// to set button background
    /// color
    /// </summary>
    public Brush Background12
    {
        get
        {
            return RiskHighLowMedium ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Blue;

        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members




}
```

Comment: I think you might need some converter. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx

Comment: Where the properties are? Are they on the UserControl or on the ViewModel?

Comment: This is a Property set on a certain condition whether the condition is true or false. these properties are on usercontrol.

Comment: First, your code works as expected for me. Second, where from update of the property is performed? Third, you better use *DependencyProperty* for all of your properties on the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need `DataTrigger` here as you are not changing anything it its setter. You will have to Raise `PropertyChanged` for `Background` also with `RiskHighLowMedium`

```
        public bool RiskHighLowMedium
        {
            get { return _riskHighLowMedium; }
            set
            {
                    _riskHighLowMedium = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("RiskHighLowMedium");
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Background12");
            }
        }
```

and in xaml

```
     <Button Name="highLowRisk" Padding="5" Grid.Column="2" Width="30" Height="30" Background={Binding Background12} Margin="5,5,5,5" />
```

Comment: Doing this way, though the background color property is changed as shown in debugging window.. but no changes as such in Button color on user interface.

Comment: have you set the DataContext of your UI to self?

Comment: this is strange.. is the default value of Background loading correctly i.e Brushes.Blue is coming on startup?

Comment: yes the default value is correct. but on property change.. color is not changed? I am trying but it's not helping :(

Comment: can you share the button xaml where you are applying this style

Comment: can you try updating your button xaml as in my updated answer.. dont apply the style

Comment: i hope you changed the Background to Background12 while testing the updated answer.. both in xaml and in OnPropertyChanged

Comment: No, it does not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps !!!

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ExampleViewModel m_ViewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_ViewModel = new ExampleViewModel();
        this.DataContext = m_ViewModel;
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_ViewModel.RiskHighLowMedium = true;
    }
}

public class ExampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _riskHighLowMedium = false;
    public ExampleViewModel()
    {

    }

    public bool RiskHighLowMedium
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _riskHighLowMedium; 
        }
        set
        {
            _riskHighLowMedium = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RiskHighLowMedium");
        }
    }

    public Brush Background
    {
        get
        {
            return RiskHighLowMedium ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Blue;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

 <Style x:Key="CircleButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RiskHighLowMedium}"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ Binding Path= Background, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

  <Grid>
    <Button Name="btn" Height="40" Width="180" Content="Hello" Style="{StaticResource CircleButtonStyle}" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```